# Sidekiq Active Job database rollback on error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, rails-api

I'm noticing that when a Sidekiq / Active Job fails due to an error being thrown, any database changes that occurred during the job are rolled back. This seems to be an intentional feature to make jobs idempotent.

My problem is that the method run by the job can send emails to users and it uses database modifications to prevent re-sending emails. If the database change is rolled back, then the email will be resent whenever the job is retried.

Here's roughly what my job looks like:

```
class ProcessPaymentsJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    begin
      # This can send emails to users.
      PaymentProcessor.perform
    rescue StandardError => error
      puts 'PaymentsJob failed, ignoring'
      puts error
    end
  end
end
```

The job is scheduled to run periodically using [sidekiq-scheduler](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler). I'm using rails-api v5.

I've added a `rescue` to try to prevent the job from rolling back the database changes but it still happens.

It occurred to me that maybe this isn't a Sidekiq issue at all but a feature of Rails.

What's the best solution here to prevent spamming the user with emails?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the database changes in a transaction inside of the PaymentProcessor, rescue the database rollback, and only send the email if the transaction succeeds. Sort of like this:

```
# ../payment_processor.rb

def perform
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    # AllTheThings.save!
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception
  # if things fail to save, handle the exception however you like
else
  # if no exception is raised, send your email
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your background job is doing too much. If sending the email has no bearing on whether the job was successful or not you should break the job into two jobs: one to send the email and another to do the other bit of processing work.

Alternatively, you could use Sidekiq Batches and make the first job above dependent on the second executing successfully.

Happy Sidekiq’ing!